# d3 means of reading proxy data via PHP

Tags: php, d3.js

In the existing SO literature, I have seen examples that use jquery and PHP to proxy data:

jquery

```
function loadTheUrl(x){      
    $.ajax({ url: 'loader.php',
         data: {url: x},
         type: 'get',
         success: function(output) {
                      $('.loading-space').html(output);
                  }
            });

  }
```

PHP

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($_GET['https://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=.NSEI&x=NSE&i=600&p=1d&f=d,o']));
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Here is what the first few lines of the data look like at the URL seen in the PHP above. It is a page of plain text only, like this:

```
MARKET_OPEN_MINUTE=570
MARKET_CLOSE_MINUTE=960
INTERVAL=300
COLUMNS=DATE,OPEN
DATA=
TIMEZONE_OFFSET=-240
a1521120900,555.45
1,554.53
2,554.07
3,553.9
4,552.67
...
```

As far as I know, the PHP is correct. For my use case, I need to replicate the above jquery by means of d3. I was hoping that d3 would have something to use to interface with the data my php file is spitting out.

If you are wondering why I am going to such lengths, it's because my browsers are not letting me run scripts (i.e. `d3.text()`, `d3.csv()` et all) directly by say `d3.text('https://www.google.com/finance...')` due to the infamous access control origin header error. So my plan is to mirror the data from the google backfill off a local php file that I'm serving from my server. This way everybody is happy (or at least me).

When I try calling `d3.text()` on my php file, my data was not loaded correctly. In other words I tried: `d3.text('my_loader.php')`. But that resulted in lots of `NaN` errors, which I usually noticed are symptoms of a parsing error of some sort. Checking back through my code, things seem fine though. I have unary parsing in place, the strings should be cast to numbers. In fact, everything was working fine offline. I could load and parse the data directly when in my IDE. It was only when I published my d3 graph to the web did I realize I couldn't parse data from different origins. This is the point where I added the PHP component. My hunch was that `d3` was actually trying to parse my PHP page and not the URL the PHP was pointing to. I later confirmed this by passing the `data` returned by `d3.text()` in the console and it was indeed the PHP page itself.

**Question:** In light of my cross-origin data situation, what can I do from the `d3` side or the `PHP` side to make the two interface with each other correctly? I wonder if d3 is only suited for same origin data, or if there actually is a method to read/parse cross-origin data using a technique I'm not aware of (PHP or otherwise).

Comment: What does the php output currently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url you are fetching does not exist within the `$_GET` variable.

The parameters you are submitting are an array:

```
$_GET = ['url' => 'some_url'];
```

Which means this:

```
$_GET['https://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=.NSEI&x=NSE&i=600&p=1d&f=d,o]
```

is wrong (it's also missing a quote mark at the end of the string).

It should be `$_GET['url']`

With no validation:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']);
```

But that's neither here nor there.

The issue, I think, is with the url being passed. It contains a question mark and multiple ampersands (`?` and `&`). I think this is bjorking up the `$_GET` parameter so all you're getting is `https://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=.NSEI`. You need to wrap the url in `encodeURIComponent`:

```
var url = encodeURIComponent('https://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=.NSEI&x=NSE&i=600&p=1d&f=d,o');
d3.text('/path/to/myscript.php?url=' + url);
```

Comment: The quote mark was a typo in my post, I checked my file too to be safe, but it was ok. Thanks for pointing that out. I tried your PHP and javascript with the encoding you suggested, but the console log is still showing that `d3.text()` is returning the contents of the PHP file, and not the url. Did you get it to return the actual data from the URL? It didn't for me; not sure how to trouble shoot it at the moment. I'm getting more hopeful though.

Comment: It is returning the php code? This suggests that you have not configured your webserver to serve php code correctly. If you are working on your local machine, what server software are you using (if *nix, Apache, PHP, Mysql; if windows, XAMP / MAMP; etc)?

Comment: Oh, that never crossed my mind. I will try deploying on my server and see if anything is different. In my local environment I'm using GitHub atom. I'm not sure if it's fully qualified as an IDE, it might be considered more of a text editor. It would be nice if it could serve PHP code though -- maybe there is a plugin or something.

Comment: That was it, the editor wasn't serving my PHP code. Once I published my PHP to the web and updated the directory, everything worked perfectly! It's so cool to get it working finally!

Answer (score 1):

Cross origin applies to all ajax requests, instead of requesting d3.text('https://www.google.com/finance...') why not try d3.text('mymethod.php') and make sure the method returns a text file rather than html via the headers:

`<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
$file = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=.NSEI&x=NSE&i=600&p=1d&f=d,o');
echo $file;`

Comment: That's what I did: "When I try calling d3.text() on my php file, my data was not loaded correctly. " I will try to edit to make it more clear, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: my bad, I didn't realize you already tried that. Why isn't the data loaded correctly? When you load it manually does it work?

Comment: No worries. yeah, I'm not sure why it doesn't read the PHP's output. The data is parsed without issue when I have a simple same origin/directory. It's my first time trying to use PHP with d3, I guess I'm not using one of the two correctly.

Comment: I've edited my answer why do you need DOMDocument for this?

Comment: You're probably right, I think `text/plain` is the way to go. I used your php and looked what was being read in `console.log(rawData)`. It read: <?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
$file = file_get_contents($_GET['http://www.google.com/finance/getprice...` So `d3.text()` is parsing the php itself and not the data that it's supposed to be pointing to. I wonder why. Is that what's happening for you too?